# Spring Integration stored procedure outbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below requirement in spring integration.

1. Receive the web service request.
2. Create a custom payload.(This will be the output of service activator)
3. Call 2 stored procedures in sql server. The first one returns an out parameter. I have to use this out parameter, as well as the list of items in the custom  payload to insert data into DB.
4. Proceed to generate the response message using the payload generated in step 2 using another service activator

Please let me know if i can achieve step 3  using jdbc stored procedure outbound gateway. Sample code will be of great help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you say is called [Content Enricher](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/DataEnricher.html) and Spring Integration has the [implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#content-enricher) on the matter.

So, you should call `enrich` sub-flow to execute the stored procedure and return that `OUT` to the main flow to enrich message not destroying the current `payload`.

We have a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/enricher) about Enricher, too.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But I did not understand "enrich sub-flow". Does that mean the output of service activator to be passed to an enricher, which internally calls a stored procedure gateway?

Comment: No, your `service-activator` with custom `payload` just sends its result to the `enricher`. That one propagates the message to some `channel` where you have your first procedure. Invoke it just reply to the `replyChannel` (the option when you don't specify `output(reply)-channel`). The result will arrive on the `enricher` which will be available to be populated to your custom payload or header. And so on.

Comment: Hi.  One more question, if the last stored procedure in the chain is not returning any value (i  am using int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter), I am not getting any message in the response channel. But I need the custom payload to be send to another service activator for furthur processing. How to achieve this?

Comment: My code looks like below <int:chain  input-channel="dbChannel" output-channel="resultPRChannel" ><int:enricher id="id1"  request-channel="geChannel"><int:property name="headers['test']" expression="payload" />        
     </int:enricher><int:enricher id="id2"  request-channel="getChannel2"    >
      
     </int:enricher>
  
 </int:chain> . The second enricher calls a procedure which returns nothing. In this scenario, I am not getting any output in resultPRChannel

Comment: You can make the `channel` for that `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter>` as `PublishSubscribeChannel` and add one more `<service-activator>` to this channel to return something logical which may identify the success of that procedure. This one exactly should be the second one (e.g. `order="2"`), so that ensures it will be invoked exactly after procedure.